# Polymer 1.x: Using iron-input to format numbers on input

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements, polymer-1.x

[In this jsBin, I format input numbers using commas](http://jsbin.com/zunezojuzu/1/edit?html,output). But is there a way to accomplish this using a Polymer element (like maybe `<iron-input` that results in less code and a solution that is more native to the platform?

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
  <link href="paper-input/paper-input.html" rel="import">
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeral.js/1.4.5/numeral.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<dom-module id="x-element">

<template>
  <style></style>

<paper-input value="{{num}}"></paper-input>

</template>

<script>
  (function(){
    Polymer({
      is: "x-element",
      properties: {
        num: {
          type: String,
          observer: '_numChanged',
        },
      },
      attached: function() {
        this.numBeingChanged = false;
      },
      _numChanged: function(num) {
        console.log('num', num);
        if (!this.numBeingChanged) {
          this.numBeingChanged = true; //prevent recursion
          var x = num.replace(/\D/g,'')
          x = parseInt(x);
          console.log('x', x);
          this.set('num', numeral(x).format('0,0'));
          this.numBeingChanged = false;
        }
      }
    });
  })();
</script>

</dom-module>

<x-element></x-element>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a job for `toLocalString()` on the `Number` prototype:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString